# Asymptotic analysis: proof that any quadratic equation asymptotically tight bounds $n^2$

Tags: analysis, algorithms, asymptotics, computer-algebra-systems

I trying to understand this assertion:

$an^2 + bn + c \in \Theta(n^2)$

By definition of $\Theta$ is possible to assume:

$0 \le c_1 n^2 \le an^2 + bn + c \le c_2 n^2$

$n \ge n_0$

So one valid proof is:

$c_1 = \frac{a}{4}$

$c_2 = 7\frac{a}{4}$

$0 \le \frac{a}{4}n^2 \le an^2 + bn + c \le 7\frac{a}{4} n^2$

$n_0 = 2 \max\left(\frac{|b|}{a}, \sqrt\frac{|c|}{a}\right)$

How can I achieve this answer?
I need to understand mainly the $n_0$ statement.

[Formula simulated in Geogebra 6](https://ggbm.at/epsmhvfn)

Answer (score 1):

To show that $an^2+bn+c\in \Theta(n^2)$ we first should notice that this is only true if $a\not=0$, otherwise it belongs to $O(n)$.

Next, recall from definition what this means:
$$
\frac{an^2+bn+c}{n^2}
$$
does not blow up to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, nor does it tend to $0$.

Simplifying the fraction we get
$$
\frac{an^2+bn+c}{n^2}=a+\frac{b}{n}+\frac{c}{n^2}.
$$
The latter two terms tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, leaving just the $a$ as the limit, which is finite and non-zero.

Comment: Can you explain the terms in this equation? $n_0 = 2 \max\left(\frac{|b|}{a}, \sqrt\frac{|c|}{a}\right)$

Comment: I think you should review the definition of a limit to see how $n_0$ enters. The definition you seem to be using for $\Theta(\cdot)$ notation seems to be a version that doesn't explicitly mention limits but that is where the $n_0$ comes from. I feel you will be more satisfied with the answers if you fully specify the question - which includes properly stating what is your definition that you are trying to show.

Answer (score 0):

$$ c_1 n^2 \le an^2 + bn + c \le c_2 n^2\iff c_1 \le a +\frac bn +\frac c{n^2} \le c_2.$$

It is obvious that the function in the middle is bounded for $n>0$ and for any $n_0$ you can find suitable $c_1,c_2$.

Comment: Can you explain the terms in this equation? $n_0 = 2 \max\left(\frac{|b|}{a}, \sqrt\frac{|c|}{a}\right)$

Comment: @Ráfagan: plug the value of $n_0$ in the quadratic expression and check the inequalities with the given $c_k$. Honestly, this sophisticated formula is overkill, boundedness is sufficient.

Comment: Look for this simulated example: https://ggbm.at/epsmhvfn. It shows in a visual way that $n_0$ is very close to be a start point for $n$. You can figure out how to evaluate quadratic equations to find the $n_0$ formula?

Comment: @Ráfagan: sorry, but this seems uninteresting/counterproductive to me. There is no point finding a precise formula for $n_0$ or $c_1,c_2$. It is enough to show that they exist. $n_0$ is so far from $\infty$...

This said, you can solve to compute the exact range of $q(n)/n^2$.